# Spring App on GCP - Cloud Run - HTTPS only - This combination of host and port requires TLS

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-run

My Spring app uses lets encrypt and is https only. I did not include http to https thing, as it worked for me in postman with https:// format

When I deployed to Cloud Run, and mentioned the custom port (the port specified in spring)
and tested using URL from dashboard

https://..blah..run.app

I am getting error/message

Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.

What configuration is required on Cloud Run to resolve this?

The url as I see on service details page has htpps://...
[image]

**EDIT:**
If Cloudrun does not need me to take case of SSL, I can remove the application properties entries

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:key/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=${lets.secret}
server.ssl.key-alias=someCertAlias
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

So Can I get an answer on whether to remove SSL from spring?
If cloudrun always uses http, all my calls use redirectConnector, which seems pointless

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Run Service listens on HTTP and HTTPS. Your application running in the container must listen on a port configured with HTTP only.

FYI: For a public facing web server, you should almost always enable HTTP. Otherwise, when a user enters **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** in the browser, the user will receive a connect error. This not always the case, for example **.dev** gTLDs, but is good practice. When a user connects to Cloud Run with the HTTP protocol, Cloud Run will redirect the user to HTTPS and connect to your application using the HTTP protocol.

Comment: My frontend is angular, and the above is the backend application. When I tested locally using both a self signed and lets encrypt, it worked .i.e. postman was able to get me jsons, angular was able to invoke my https endpoints. I can add some code that does port mappaing, but if this works as-is with some config in CloudRun then it would be great

Comment: @Southstar - I do not understand your comment. Your application running in Cloud Run must listen on a port configured with HTTP and not HTTPS. What you tested locally with self-signed certificates does not apply to Cloud Run.

Comment: I was clarifying that this app not my main UI. Do I need to implement the redirect http to https as in 7. FAQ of   https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-examples/ My app is gradle, still above article with embedded tomcat ok?

Comment: You seem to be stuck on HTTP and HTTPS. Read the Cloud Run documentation on how to build, configure and deploy an application. There are many tutorials available showing you the steps to create and deploy Spring Boot on Cloud Run.

Comment: I am not stuck, I have explicitly blocked http. The solution I know to enable my application to allow http also is by having a redirectConnector in the boot application. The example is maven, where as I use gradle, so asked whether tomcat or jetty. In this way, Cloudrun invokes http, and application uses connector to serve. I read this line on Cloud Run, "Should listen for HTTP requests on $PORT and not rely on local state. How to build a container?" but now I am confused whether I need to remove my ssl feature

Comment: "container must listen on a port configured with HTTP only" So can I assume CloudRun already gives me ssl, and I dont need ssl from app